# python MySQL module class file name

Tags: python, file, class, directory, module

I am confused how directory name, file name and class name all work together.

This is what I have at the moment

```
  app.py
  database/
     client.py
     staff.py
     order.py
```

Inside `client.py` I have a single class called `client`, which acts as the database model (MVC). The same with my other files: `staff.py` has a class called `staff`, `order.py` has `order`.

Then in `app.py` I do:

```py
  from database import client as model
  c = model.client()
```

And then I get confused. In an ideal world **this is what I want to do**:

1. Keep my database model classes in separate files in their own directory.
2. Use them like this:

```py
  c = model.client()
  o = model.order()
  s = model.staff()
```

The only way I can see to do this is to put all my classes in a single file called `model.py` and save this at the root.

I'm sure I am missing something very basic here.

Comment: So am I right that your problem is that you have a class with name X in a file with name X and all those files in a package called Y and you want to simply say Y.X() (and thus save one mention of X) ?

Comment: I don't know - I don't have either X or Y ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has two basic ways of importing content.  Modules and Packages.

---

A module is simply a python file on the include path: **order.py**

If order.py defines a class named **foo**, then access to that class could be had by:

```
import order
o = order.foo()
```

In order to use the syntax from the orignial question, you would need to ensure that your **model.py** file has the following attributes: [client, staff, order]

However, that typically means placing them in a single file.  Which is what you are trying to avoid.

---

A package is a directory with an **__init__.py** inside of it.  The **init**.py initializes the package (ie. it is run on first import), and you can have either modules or sub-packages within that directory.

```
model
    __init__.py
    client.py
    staff.py
    order.py
```

That way, to access any of the sub modules, you would simply say:

```
import model.client
```

However, that is simply importing the module.  It is not importing any of the attributes of the module.  So in order to access a class inside the module, you would need to specify it:

```
import model.client
o = model.client.clientclass()
```

This is a bit tedious, but very well organized.

---

**Best of both (where performance isn't a big deal):**

If you type the following code in **__init__.py**:

```
from .client import clientclass as client
from .staff import staffclass as staff
from .order import orderclass as order
```

Then you have auto-loaded all of your classes, and they can be accessed as:

```
import model
c = model.client()
s = model.staff()
o = model.order()
```

---

In the end, it may be more simple to stick with the non-magical way to do it:

```
import model.client
o = model.client.clientclass()
```

--Gahooa

Comment: another question: does the verbose way [o = model.client.clientclass()] leak implementation details into the code? Say during refactoring you decide to move a class (e.g. clientclass) into its own file, you need to change the hundreds of lines where you make a new clientclass. (I'm out of chars..)

Comment: @monk.e.boy: Performance is reduced because all of the files are imported even if you only need one.  If it is a long running process, or a simple program, no problem.  But if it is to be loaded a lot, it can have an impact.

Comment: @monk.e.boy: Implementation details should (IMO) be at the class level, not the module level.  In other words, implementers should know the public class names at some point.